# Spring Security и проблема с Dialog Framework Primefaces

Tags: java, spring, jsf, spring-security

Доброго времени суток! Есть приложение, использующее Spring, JSF, Primefaces. Сейчас решил подключить Spring Security. Всё работает корректно, за исключением того, что перестали открываться окна Dialog Framework внутри приложения.  
 Т.е. когда нажимаю на кнопку, запускающую в контроллере метод

```
public void addUserDialog(){
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().openDialog("addUser", props, null);
}
```

Ничего не происходит, ошибки при этом никакой нет. Если страницу "addUser.xhtml" вызывать напрямую, например через гиперссылку со страницы, то всё работает и форма появляется. После отключения в web.xml Spring security всё работает нормально. Ошибок ни на каком этапе не возникает. Есть какие-нибудь идеи, в чём может быть дело? 
 
**web.xml**

```
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>login/login.xhtml</welcome-file>
```

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
</listener>


<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath:spring/application-context.xml
        /WEB-INF/security-context.xml
        /WEB-INF/springsecurity.taglib.xml
    </param-value>


</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>cupertino</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

Spring security
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

**faces-config.xml**

```
<application>
    <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
    <locale-config>
        <default-locale>ru</default-locale>
        <supported-locale>en</supported-locale>
    </locale-config>
    <resource-bundle>
        <base-name>locales.messages</base-name>
        <var>msg</var>
    </resource-bundle>
    <message-bundle>
        validation-messages
    </message-bundle>
    <action-listener>
        org.primefaces.application.DialogActionListener
    </action-listener>
    <navigation-handler>
        org.primefaces.application.DialogNavigationHandler
    </navigation-handler>
    <view-handler>
        org.primefaces.application.DialogViewHandler
    </view-handler>
</application>

<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>/login/login.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <to-view-id>/pages/manager.xhtml</to-view-id>
        <from-outcome>manager</from-outcome>
        <redirect/>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>/pages/manager.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <to-view-id>/j_spring_security_logout?faces-redirect=true</to-view-id>
        <from-outcome>exit</from-outcome>
        <redirect/>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

**security-context.xml**

```
   <security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">

          <security:csrf disabled="true"/>

          <security:intercept-url pattern="/pages/*" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
          <security:form-login login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check" default-target-url="/pages/manager.xhtml"
                               login-page="/login/login.xhtml" authentication-failure-url="/login/loginFailed.xhtml"
                  username-parameter="user" password-parameter="pass"/>
          <security:logout invalidate-session="true" logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout" logout-success-url="/login/login.xhtml"/>
   </security:http>

   <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
          <security:authentication-provider>
                 <security:user-service>
                        <security:user name="admin" password="admin" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
                        <security:user name="user" password="user" authorities="ROLE_USER"/>
                 </security:user-service>
          </security:authentication-provider>
   </security:authentication-manager>
```

**Структура проекта** 
 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

В итоге проблема решилась, когда я поменял версию Spring Security с 4.0.2 на 3.2.8.